# Group Powershell array then convert to json

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I have looked through several threads but have been unable to find a solution to my problem. Basically I have an array that looks like so:
[image: array sample]

I am ultimately trying to group this by state and then convert it to json with an output like so:

```
{
  "NY": [
    "auto",
    "food"
  ],
  "CA": [
    "retail",
    "health",
    "auto"
  ],
  "TX": [
    "retail",
    "insurance"
  ]
}
```

I am sort of stuck here on how to get this done and can't seem to get it to the format that I am looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to build an object that has the exact same format as the JSON you want to output, probably the easiest way in your specific case would be:

```
$Data = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="NY";Type="auto"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="NY";Type="food"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="CA";Type="retail"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="CA";Type="health"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="CA";Type="auto"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="TX";Type="retail"}
    [PSCustomObject]@{State="TX";Type="insurance"}
)

$Obj = @{}

foreach ($Group in ($Data | Group State)) {
    $Obj[$Group.Name] = ($Group.Group | Select -Expand Type)
}

$Obj | ConvertTo-Json
```

which will output exactly:

```
{
    "TX":  [
               "retail",
               "insurance"
           ],
    "NY":  [
               "auto",
               "food"
           ],
    "CA":  [
               "retail",
               "health",
               "auto"
           ]
}
```

The way you format it will vary wildly depending on your input and output formats, but hopefully this helps you get an idea of it for similar issues as well.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help! I had spent way too much time trying to get that one. It makes much more sense now.

Comment: Not gonna assert this is more readable or better, but it's useful for command line usage. This can be done as a pipeline: `... | foreach {$out = @{}} { $out[$_.name] = $_.group.type } { $out }`. The property broadcasting ($_.group.type) is powershell 3, the begin/process/end for foreach is older. In full scripts you should at least name the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show any code, so lets assume your data stems from a csv file

```
> import-csv .\data.csv

State Type
----- ----
NY    auto
NY    food
CA    retail
CA    health
CA    auto
TX    retail
TX    insurance
```

Grouping on state yields this:

```
Import-Csv .\data.csv | Group-Object state

Count Name Group
----- ---- -----
    2 NY   {@{State=NY; Type=auto}, @{State=NY; Type=food}}
    3 CA   {@{State=CA; Type=retail}, @{State=CA; Type=health}, @{State=CA; Type=auto}}
    2 TX   {@{State=TX; Type=retail}, @{State=TX; Type=insurance}}
```

But you only need the state once and the types out of each group,
so try to unroll in an array and ConvertTo-Json:

```
> Import-Csv .\data.csv|Group-Object state|ForEach{@{$_.Name = $_.Group.Type}}|ConvertTo-Json
[
    {
        "NY":  [
                   "auto",
                   "food"
               ]
    },
    {
        "CA":  [
                   "retail",
                   "health",
                   "auto"
               ]
    },
    {
        "TX":  [
                   "retail",
                   "insurance"
               ]
    }
]
```

That looks similar but not the desired.

---

Try to see how an object looks like when converting the other way around:

```
@"
{
  "NY": [
    "auto",
    "food"
  ],
  "CA": [
    "retail",
    "health",
    "auto"
  ],
  "TX": [
    "retail",
    "insurance"
  ]
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

NY           CA                     TX
--           --                     --
{auto, food} {retail, health, auto} {retail, insurance}
```

At this point it was my intention to abort the lesson and leave some coding to you,
but [colsw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3694461/colsw) good answer saves you from that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the command-line tool [jq](/questions/tagged/jq).  To simplify things, let's assume the following jq script is in a file named program.jq, and that the file states.csv contains the state/type table as a CSV file:

```
[inputs | sub(",";"\t") | split("\t") | {state: .[0], type: .[1]}]
| group_by(.state)
| map({ (.[0]|.state) : map(.type)})
| add
```

This changes the first "," in each line to a tab, then splits the line, forms an object, etc.

### Invocation

If states.csv has a header row:

```
jq -nR -f program.jq states.csv
```

Otherwise, just use -R instead of -nR.